# Is there an equivalent for MySQL's "multi_query()" in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, multi-query

I like assembling multiple SQL queries into one string and executing them simultaneously to ensure that they are executed atomically. I can't seem to do this with PDO like I could with the MySQL functions though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want atomicity, use transactions and prepared statements rather than trying to issue multiple queries delimited by semicolon. Prepared statements **should** also execute faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending at once multiple queries to the MySQL server - won't make them atomic. For atomicity, use transactions. Read: [ACID @ wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)