# how create auto increment column on the fly in mysql with php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, auto-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent for MySQL's “multi_query()” in PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832501/is-there-an-equivalent-for-mysqls-multi-query-in-pdo)

I have two table, I do a union from two table:

```
 select * 
 from table1
 union 
 select *
 from table2
```

I would want create an auto increment column on the fly for creating "more results" pagination passing this auto increment id as offset.

I can create auto increment column on the fly in this way:

```
SELECT @i:=0;

SELECT all_res.*, 
       @i:=@i+1 AS i 
FROM (
 select * 
 from table1
 union 
 select *
 from table2
) as all_res
```

but if I run queries in php pdo I obtain this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 SELECT all_res.*, @i:=@i+1 AS i' at line 1
```

How can I do for obtain an unique column id to be able to "view more results"?

Comment: Just define the column that you want as `AUTO_INCREMENT` -  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: see this post: [Get row number on select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)

Comment: but I want auto_increment on union query result, in table1 and table2 I have already an auto_increment column

Comment: Are you trying to execute those two `SELECT`s in a single `PDO::query` call?

Comment: @lanzz: Just thought the same, this looks like it!

Comment: Comments turn out that user is just pushing stuff to the database without first checking if things are applicatable or not. then pushing errors into stackoverflow. Voting for duplicate now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO: one query at a time. Not two queries. Use mysqli for that it has multi query support.

See as well:

- [Is there an equivalent for MySQL's “multi_query()” in PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832501/is-there-an-equivalent-for-mysqls-multi-query-in-pdo)
- [How to execute mysql script with variables using PHP::PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683110/how-to-execute-mysql-script-with-variables-using-phppdo)

Comment: In PDO isn't possible to do it?

Comment: You can perform the two queries separately. Custom variables persist between queries, as long as you're in the same connection.